# Getting 3d acceleration working in Windows 7 64bit on Mac Boot Camp?

Tags: windows-7, mac, 64-bit, macbook, boot-camp

I've installed the Windows 7 RC 64-bit edition under boot camp, but I'm have zero luck getting the 3D acceleration working.

I've installed all the Mac drivers (including the 64bit Nvidia ones on the OSX install cd), I've also run the windows update and I still am not getting the full aero desktop.

I'm trying to do this on the latest unibody Macbook, with the duel NVIDIA GeForce 9400M + 9600M GT.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just installed Windows 7 x64 on a 9400M Mac Mini over the weekend.  I have full Aero and 3D games work great.  Just hit up http://www.nvidia.com:

- Click Download Drivers
- **Product Type:** Geforce
- **Product Series:** Geforce 9M Series (Notebooks)
- **Operating System:** Windows 7 64 bit
- Click Search

Download and install the drivers, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I am so use to laptops drivers not being available as a download I didn't even think of this. Now if only my Macbook didn't get hot enough to fry an egg under windows.

Answer (score 3):

Have you run the Windows Experience Index tool again? (Control Panel > System and Security > System > Check the Windows Experience Index)

If you have only run it before installing your drivers, Windows won't run Aero because it thinks it is still running with crappy hardware. Try running it again in order to enable Aero. This has worked for me on a Mac Mini running Windows 7.

Comment: I did need to do this after installing the drivers as recommend by Curtis and Stefan.

Answer (score 2):

Check out what graphics chipset is actually in the mac and install the drivers for that chipset from the Nvidia website.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated the question with the chipset.

Comment: Traditionally, drivers for laptops are not available on the chipset manufacturers website, is this not the case for the Macbooks?

Comment: Sometimes there are drivers available on the manufacturers homepage. I found some for my Zepto 6234 that has an Nvidia 8600GT chipset, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You will get better battery life if you use the drivers from Boot Camp 3.0 on the Snow Leopard disk. On my MacBook Pro unibody 2009, I get life in the 4-5 hours range with the NVidia driver Apple supplies with Snow Leopard Boot Camp 3.0 and 2-2.5 hours with the latest driver available from NVidia.com.

Update: 
There are newer official NVidia OEM compatiblie drivers available than the ones bundled with Boot Camp 3.0. These work without hacking the INFs. Laptop Video To Go has archived the 186.03 x86 and x64 drivers from NVidia's site.

- http://www.laptopvideo2go.com/drivers/win7x32/186.03/disclaimer
- http://www.laptopvideo2go.com/drivers/win7x64/186.03/disclaimer

Just make sure NVAO.inf from additional_infs.zip is extracted and the 186.03 driver will install and work.

There are also more recent BETA quality drivers archived at laptop video to go.